# SFML - How to get expected string width?

Tags: c++, sfml

How to get the expected sf::String's width when drawn on the window? Currently I only know how to get the sf::String's heigh, with the GetSize() method.

OBS: I'm using SFML v1.6 on Linux.

Comment: Note: SFML 1.6 is *ancient*. You really ought to move to 2.4.2 at this point.

Comment: Yes, I was using it because it was pre-installed on the university's PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1String.php), `sf::String` has a `GetRect` member function which returns a `sf::Rect< float >`, with a `GetWidth()` member.

```
float width = str.GetRect().GetWidth();
```

Comment: George, your answer almost got it. `GetRect().GetWidth()` did the trick. On SFML 1.6, the field `width` was a `GetWidth()` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could go through `sf::Font::GetImage` which returns the drawn glyphs of the font, and after you can use `sf::Image::GetWidth`.

Also, unless you have a very good reason to stay with 1.6, I would highly suggest you update to a more recent version. 1.6 is more than 7 years old. It is not supported and has a few bugs.